# Orange star like ight

Tags: star

Tonight high up in the night sky, it was 8.20 precisely, I saw a bright orange light floating slowly across the sky ,occasionally slowing as if looking for something and flickering, it was too high up and far away to see an exact shape, but it looked like a star, so was it a star, do we have bright orange stars

Comment: We would need far more information to be able to answer you - e.g. location

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to astronomy.  This is not the place for ufo reports.

Answer (score 2):

> I saw a bright orange light floating slowly across the sky ,occasionally slowing as if looking for something
>
> it looked like a star, so was it a star,

For the sake of teaching some scientific reasoning skills, I'll point out that just because you think it looks like a star does not mean it is a star.

In fact the motion of the object suggests it was not a star.  Stars do not move except as part of a general motion of the night sky dues to Earth's rotation.  What you describe is not that.

When we try and work out what something is, we use all the evidence.

What would it be like ?  Perhaps a helicopter with lights.